Highlighting a Keyword with a Red Rectangle in listings Environment (XML Language)
How can I highlight the keyword myINSTRUMENT with a red rectangle inside a listings environment (using language=xml)? Please see below MY CODE, MY OUTPUT and MY DESIRED OUTPUT.
MY CODE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml]
    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugin assembly="Instruments">
    <messageassemblies>
        <messageassembly>Component.Messages</messageassembly>
    </messageassemblies>
    <components>
        <component name="myINSTRUMENT" type="Instrument">
            <class>Instruments.Configuration</class>
        </component>
    </components>
</plugin>

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

MY OUTPUT:

MY DESIRED OUTPUT:

